# How to fix Ubuntu 22.04 UEFI boot GPT issues after simple dd clone to larger disk

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, uefi, clone, gparted

1. I have a healthy Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation on a 1TB SSD

It's a simple disk-- not using LVM, just two partitions: the 512 MiB EFI System Partition and the rest is one big ext4 partition for the OS & data. Using secure boot "Other OS" with my ASUS z490 motherboard, works great.

2. I want to switch this installation to a new 2TB SSD. Both SSDs installed in my PC.
3. I boot into a Ubuntu 22.04 live USB and use gparted to shrink the ext4 "OS & data" partition down to 250GiB, leaving 10% free space (so `dd` won't have to run for so long)
4. I run `sudo dd conv=noerror,sync iflag=fullblock status=progress bs=65536 count=3412345 if=/dev/1TB_SSD of=/dev/2TB_SSD` -- works great, completes in about 20 minutes
5. Reboot and my BIOS tells me there is a GPT problem. New 2TB installation not listed as bootable in the BIOS.
6. Boot the 1TB SSD into Ubuntu, run gparted, which automatically detects there is an issue (I think with the partition table) on the 2TB SSD, run the suggested fix, completes with no errors.

However, there is still a a red "!" next to the EFI System Partition in gparted, and when I right-click "Information" it says

> Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for fat32 file system support: dosfstools, mtools.

My BIOS no longer shows an error screen when I boot, but my new 2TB SSD is still not listed as bootable (probably failing some UEFI check?).

Obviously there is some incompatibility between the EFI System Partition (copied exactly from the 1TB SSD) and my new 2TB SSD.

How do I fix this so I can use my install on the new 2TB SSD?

Comment: Using dd to copy to a larger disk will corrupt the GPT partitioning, since it will place the secondary GPT on the target disk in the same relative position as on the source disk, whereas it should be at the very end of the disk. Don't know what the problem is with the ESP filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: I gave up on the `dd` approach completely and started over with Clonezilla. That worked on the first try, without requiring much thought or research. Thanks so much to the Clonezilla team!

If anyone wants to give a real answer to my original question, that's still welcome, but I won't (be able to) test it out.